# JavaScript: Sort based on several methods simultaneously

Tags: javascript, sorting

I'm trying to work out how to use multiple methods of sorting at once.

For example, say I have 3 ways of sorting numbers:

```js
function weightedSort() {

    var outputArea = document.getElementById("outputArea");

    var distanceWeight = document.getElementById("distanceSlider").value;
    var largestWeight = document.getElementById("largestSlider").value;
    var smallestWeight = document.getElementById("smallestSlider").value;

    var numbers = [1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9, 13, 40, 500];

    outputArea.value = numbers.sort(function(a, b) {

        var distanceResult = Math.abs(4 - a) - Math.abs(4 - b);
        var largestResult = b - a;
        var smallestResult = a - b;

        var distanceWeighted = distanceResult * distanceWeight;
        var largestWeighted = largestResult * largestWeight;
        var smallestWeighted = smallestResult * smallestWeight;

        return distanceWeighted + largestWeighted + smallestWeighted;

    }).join("\n");
}
```

```html
<div>
    <label for="distanceSlider">Closest to 4</label>
    <input id="distanceSlider" type="range" min="0" max="1"value="0" step="0.01" oninput="weightedSort();">

    <label for="largestSlider">Largest</label>
    <input id="largestSlider" type="range" min="0" max="1" value="0" step="0.01" oninput="weightedSort();">

    <label for="smallestSlider">Smallest</label>
    <input id="smallestSlider" type="range" min="0" max="1" value="0" step="0.01" oninput="weightedSort();">
</div>

<textarea id="outputArea" rows="9" cols="20">
1
3
4
5
7
9
13
40
500
</textarea>
```

Is there a way I could sort using a fraction of each of these methods?

For example, 100% "Closest to 4" and 100% "Largest" would attempt to find the largest numbers closest to 4.

In the code above I added the weights together, but this causes many problems. For example, if the largest number was 1 million and the smallest was 1, "largestResult" would be so large it couldn't be overcome by other sorting methods. I'm also not sure it produces the right result mathematically speaking.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: hi, interesting, perhaps specify a sort function in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: I did in my example. I'm not sure how to properly incorporate multiple methods at once though.

Comment: Maybe use a logarithmic scale for each method instead of a linear scale?

Comment: Also the callback for `Array.sort()` method should return `-1`, `0` or `1`.

Comment: How is it expected to have largest and smallest sortings at the same time?

Comment: @farhodius No, it simply needs to return a *number*, where the sign of the number determines the relative sort order.

Comment: My recommendation is to define some use cases or scenarios with the input and the expected output, start with a clear simple case, and built more on it later, reduce the scope and take steps to do it, as for now I can't expect the output or the expected behavior in different cases

Comment: @Zac Yes, this is a good idea. Largest and smallest indeed contradict, but I included both for the sake of the example. I'm trying to work out myself what the output should be, but I keep getting confused.

Comment: I believe that the implementation would be different based on the example, to have one generic sorting method that works for any number of different sorting mechanisms is not a simple thing to do in one step, it could be doable, but I'd highly recommend you to start with simple specific cases and then try to enhace the code to cover more cases